# Validating a Checkbox in a datagrid C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have an unbound datagrid that has two columns that are defined as checkboxes.

What I'm trying to accomplish is performing validation when a user clicks on any column that appears in the delete column. In some instances I don't want the user to be able to delete certain records.

While working on this, I discovered that neither the CellValidating or CellValueChanged methods are getting called each time I click in a cell in the Delete column.

I've read similar questions but I have yet to find exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort in answering my question.

[image]

var checkBox = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

```
            var isCheck = checkBox?.Value;
            var check = isCheck == null ? false : bool.Parse(isCheck.ToString());

            if (isCheck != null)
                checkBox.Value = !check;        // change checkbox value

            if (!check) // if value was false, it's being changed to true
            {
                string sShipToId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ColumnHeaders.ShipToIDColumn].Value.ToString();
                string sDelete = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ColumnHeaders.DeleteColumn].Value.ToString();


                // need to check to see if this ship to is associated with an open order. if it is
                // we can't delete it. This mimics the functionality that P21 exhibits when you try to delete
                // a ship to from the Ship To Maintenance screen.
                // we also need to check and see if we're deleting the Ship to associated with the  current order.

                ShipToInfo Ship = new ShipToInfo(Server, Database);

                if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sShipTo) == false) &&
                        (sShipToId.Equals(sShipTo) == true) ||
                        (Ship.ShipToExistsInOpenOrder(sShipToId, CompanyID) == true))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Open orders exist for this Ship To " + sShipToId + ". It cannot be deleted.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    dataGridView1_CellContentClick(null, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event for Checked in the checkbox, and apply your logic there.
https://www.dotnetperls.com/checkbox-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CellContentClick` event to work with Checkboxes in `DataGridView`. I dynamically created the `DataGridView` object `MyDataGridView`. You can do it using designer as well. I am not sure how you want to use the value of the `CheckBox` but if you use it you should change its value manually in `CellContentClick` event as it is below.

```
private DataGridView MyDataGridView = new DataGridView();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetupDataGridView();
}

private void SetupDataGridView()
{
    this.Controls.Add(MyDataGridView);
    MyDataGridView.ColumnCount = 2;

    MyDataGridView.Name = "MyDataGridView";
    MyDataGridView.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    MyDataGridView.Size = new Size(500, 300);

    MyDataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
    MyDataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "Value";

    MyDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { Name = "Default" });
    MyDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { Name = "Delete" });

    MyDataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "one", true, true);
    MyDataGridView.Rows.Add("2", "two", false, true);
    MyDataGridView.Rows.Add("3", "three", true, false);

    MyDataGridView.CellContentClick += MyDataGridView_CellContentClick;
}

private void MyDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // get value of checkbox
    var checkBox = MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    var isCheck = checkBox?.Value;
    var check = isCheck == null ? false : bool.Parse(isCheck.ToString());

    if (isCheck != null)            
        checkBox.Value = !check;        // change checkbox value

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && check)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure", 
            "Delete Row", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It seems to do what I want it to do. The only additional question I have is I want to uncheck the checkbox programmatically. Since this isn't a validation function can I return a value that will cause .Net to uncheck the checkbox or do I have to do that myself ?

Comment: @L.Levine You can easily uncheck the checkbox programmatically. One of the quickest solutions is to call the event handler manually. For example, call this `MyDataGridView_CellContentClick(null, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, 0));` Here `2` is the `ColumnIndex` and `0` is the `RowIndex`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks !

Comment: Turns out I was premature in my stating that this worked. While CellContentClickgets called again, the checkbox isn't being unchecked even though checkBox.Value is being set to false.

Comment: Calling this method is equivalent of checking/unchecking the checkbox by hand. Pay attention to the used indexes. or give me the specific example when it does not work.

Comment: test it using a button: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){MyDataGridView_CellContentClick(null, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, 0));}`

Comment: The situation where it doesn't work is when the user selects a cell in the Delete column and I want to uncheck the cell because the row fails "validation".